# how to sort and select top 5 elements in a json array using angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, highcharts

I have a REST API which returns a Java.util.HashMap object as JSON.

It has data in the form (some 15-20 elements like this):

```
"entity": {
    "element1": 15,
    "element2": 26,
    "element3": 37,
    "element4": 45
}
```

I am calling the API and getting this map in my Angular JS application as follows:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8080/dummy/';
console.log(url);
$http.get(url).success(function(data) {
    var elements = [];
    var counts = [];
    var mymap = data.entity;
    console.log(mymap);
    Object.keys(mymap).forEach(function(key) {
        elements.push(key);
        counts.push(mymap[key]);
    });
})
```

Next, I am using this to display it as a bar graph in the UI using high charts:

```
Highcharts.chart('hc-container', {
chart : {
    type : 'bar'
},
title : {
    text : 'Top 5 element count'
},
xAxis : {
    categories : elements
},
series : [ {
    name : 'count',
    data : counts
} ]
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
  <div id="hc-container">Placeholder for chart</div>
</body>
```

Now currently it is showing all the elements from the map. I only need the top 5 elements with the highest counts to be displayed in the bar graph.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you share your HTML?

Comment: added the HTML as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the keys by their associated count value and [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the result:

```js
let data = {
    "entity": {
      "element1": 1,
      "element2": 2,
      "element3": 3,
      "element4": 4,
      "element5": 5,
      "element6": 6,
      "element7": 7
    }
  },

  mymap = data.entity;


let elements = Object.keys(mymap)
  .sort((a, b) => mymap[b] - mymap[a])
  .slice(0, 5);

let counts = elements.map(key => mymap[key]);

console.log('5 highest counts', JSON.stringify(counts))
console.log('5 highest elements', JSON.stringify(elements))
```

Comment: what does `.sort((a, b) => mymap[a] - mymap[b])` do? 
Also, would this sort based on the count of the elements present in the map?

Comment: my mistake...fixed sort..was backwards. It sorts the keys array by the associated count

Answer (score 0):

You could use the angularJS **$filter** service to do the sorting and top n:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("soDemo", []);
  app.controller("soDemoController", SoDemoController);

  SoDemoController.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];

  function SoDemoController($scope, $filter) {
    var vm = {
      counts: [{
          name: 'element1',
          count: 15
        },
        {
          name: 'element2',
          count: 26
        },
        {
          name: 'element3',
          count: 37
        },
        {
          name: 'element4',
          count: 45
        }
      ]
    };

    var limitToFilter = $filter('limitTo');
    vm.sortedCounts = limitToFilter($filter('orderBy')(vm.counts, '-count'), 3);
    $scope.vm = vm;
    return;
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="sample" ng-app="soDemo" ng-controller="soDemoController">
  <h2>Counts</h2>
  <pre>{{vm.counts | json}}</pre>
  <h2>Sorted Counts (top 3)</h2>
  <pre>{{vm.sortedCounts | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys an map.

```
const entity = {
  "element1": 99,
  "element2": 15,
  "element3": 26,
  "element4": 37,
  "element5": 45,
  "element6": 2
};

const result = Object.keys(entity).map(key => ({ key, value: entity[key] })).sort((elemA, elemB) => {
  if (elemA.value > elemB.value) {
    return -1;
  } else if (elemB.value > elemA.value) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}).slice(0, 5);
//
// [ { key: 'element1', value: 99 },
//   { key: 'element5', value: 45 },
//   { key: 'element4', value: 37 },
//   { key: 'element3', value: 26 },
//   { key: 'element2', value: 15 } ]
console.log(result);
```

Just add another map or reduce in the end get the result in desired format.